# Explanation on exponent of cardinal (Set Theory and Metric Spaces - Kaplanski)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I think I understand most of the following discussion. However, the highlighted phrase was too opaque for me to follow

[image]

Could you please explain:

1. What do the notations $\pi$<sub>1</sub>*f* and $\pi$<sub>2</sub>*f* refer to?
2. Are *H(E, D<sub>1</sub>)* and *H(E, D<sub>2</sub>)* the coordinates of the plane *H(E, D<sub>1</sub>)* x *H(E, D<sub>2</sub>)*?
3. Why is the ordered pair ($\pi$<sub>1</sub>*f*, $\pi$<sub>2</sub>*f*) an element of *H(E, D<sub>1</sub>)* x *H(E, D<sub>2</sub>)*?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are known as the forgetful maps, forgetting the second and first element of the ordered pair, respectively. So, $\pi_1f$ refers to $\pi_1\circ f$, i.e., apply the function $f$ to $e\in E$, and take the first coordinate.

Comment: To your second question, the answer is yes. To your third, I think you now have the tools to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @DonThousand I don't think I have heard that terminology before. I have usually seen it referred to as a "projection map."

Comment: Thanks, @DonThousand. Just to clarify: you mean forgetful map only forgets/ignores the **second** element (not **second and first** element) of an order pair (that is, the element $\pi_2$ *f* in this case)? Why only forgetting the second element, not the first? And I thought the notation $\pi_1$ *f* means applying function $\pi_1$ to function *f*?

Comment: @DonThousand.  Amateur expression..

Comment: @WilliamElliot Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: @Nemo.  The first projection $\pi_1$ projects a point (x,y) onto the first coordinate.   For example, the set extended first projection of the unit circle is [0,1].  Forget "forgetful," it is an uncommon term.

Comment: @DonThousand.  The $\pi$'s are called projections. For example, the projection of a circle onto a line. The peculiar nomenclature "forgetful" is an amateur expression omitting the spacial sense of the projections. The shift operator could also be called "forgetful" for those who forget the common term.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Ah, you were calling it/me amateur. Well, I think forgetful map as a term is more common than you give it credit for, given that its generalization, the forgetful functor, is also in common usage.

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamElliot. I accept the $\pi$'s are the projection onto the coordinates. But could you please explain what ($\pi_1$ *f*, $\pi_2$ *f*) refers to?

Answer (score 1):

An example of ($\pi_1$f, $\pi_2$f).

x(t) = sin t, y(t) = cos t is a parametric equation of a circle.
Restating the same parametric equation
f(t) = (sin t, cos t)
= ($\pi_1$(sin t, cos t), $\pi_2$(sin t, cos t)
= ($\pi_1$f(t), $\pi_2$f(t))

So when f is a function into a product of two sets,
($\pi_1$f, $\pi_2$f) is explicating the coordinate values of f.
(Note that f can be a function of multiple variables.)

Comment: Thanks for proposing the answer, @WilliamElliot. Just to verify I understand it, I rephrase your explanation based on the terms of the Kaplanski text as follows: $\pi_1$ *f* is the projection of (or is explicating ) *f* into $H$($E$, $D_1$)?

Comment: @Nemo.  f is into $H(E, D_1) × H(E, D_2),$ a product of two sets which is what I described.